# (Why) is log4net not under development anymore?

Tags: logging, log4net

Looking at [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html) seems to hint, that log4net is not really under development anymore. Is that true? Why so? I'd think there actually is room for improvements/new features. Things like .NET 4.0, fluent configuration, WCF or new platforms come into mind. What's the story here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that they picked up development again. Newer Versions can be downloaded here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html

**Update 30.06.2016**: While there have been new versions released, it does not seem to be a very active project. The issue tracker shows little activity:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET/

Comment: Accepted answer is now from 5 years ago. That link doesn't go anywhere and I'm asking the same question now!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the link and my answer.

Comment: It's as simple as Dan J's answer below - the people who've worked on log4net (myself included) have left, found new priorities or simply lack the time (I'd put myself here) and no other developer's have shown up to drive the project forward.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else arrived here because they couldn't find current project information (like myself), development is still ongoing for log4net.

At current, most of the activity for log4net is available via their github repo here:
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net

and the commit log here:
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/commits/develop

While the download link mentioned in Stefan's answer appears to have disappeared, the preferred way to obtain log4net is via NuGet. The profile page at NuGet for log4net shows nominal release activity with the latest release in March 2017 (2.0.8 at time of writing).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/

Answer (score 0):

It might be that there are several superior frameworks available. But I am just speculating.

Comment: Nope, that is not the case. AFAIK, the only serious free alternative is the logging block of the enterprise library.

Comment: bitbonk, Are you aware of NLog? AFAIK it has very similar capabilities to log4net. The developer (is there only one?) is apparently currently making a big development push for NLog2.0. The document on the website, http://nlog-project.org/, is not that great because he is converting to wiki and not all documentation has been migrated. You can, however, find better (albeit older) documentation here: http://nlog-project.org/help/

Comment: NLog looks like a good choice, but I'd argue that the standard logging framework for a company should hide away whether the implementation is log4net, NLog or something entirely different. Things change, and the best answer for some questions is the worst for others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an open-source project being developed as part of the [Apache Logging Services](http://logging.apache.org/). Jump in there and [finish version 1.2.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel). ;)

Looks like their [last commit](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.subversion:subversion-project-tab) was in late 2009...

Also looks like Ron Grabowski could answer this question... :)

Comment: Strange, it seems that there are only 15 of 49 issues left needed for the 1.2.11 release...